# Can we use both custom validation (using clean()) and inbuilt validators in a single Django-form field ? If /if-not how/why?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using an inbuilt validator to check the length of a form element, also using the custom clean() method to check for another logic not present in the inbuilt validators. But getting an error. Is this allowed in Django? if yes, then please show me an example.

my forms.py :

```
class loginForm(forms.Form):
    gender_options=[('male','Male'),('female','Female')]
    username=forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput,validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(5),
                                                                              validators.MaxLengthValidator(15)])
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True,widget=forms.EmailInput,validators=[validators.EmailValidator])
    password=forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput,validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(8)])
    gender=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=gender_options))

    def clean(self):
        user_cleaned_data=super().clean()
        password_1=user_cleaned_data['password']
        flag=False   # to find atleast 1 uppercase letter
        if not set(password_1).intersection(string.ascii_uppercase):
            raise ValidationError('password','Password must have atleast one uppercase letter')
```

Comment: It is allowed to use both yes. But without sharing the details of the validator/inbuilt check, it is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: added my forms code. Please kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to make use of the [**`min_length=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.min_length) and [**`min_length=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.max_length) parameters. These will automatically add validators, but it makes it more clean. An [**`EmailField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield) furthermore already works with an `EmailValidator`, so there is no need to manually add an extra one:

```
class loginForm(forms.Form):
    gender_options=[('male','Male'),('female','Female')]
    username=forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=15
    )
    email=forms.EmailField()
    password=forms.CharField(min_length=8)
    gender=forms.ChoiceField(choices=gender_options)

    # …
```

form fields are by default [**`required=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#required) and a lot of the widgets you use are also the default, so we here remove a lot of "noise".

As for the `clean` method, you need to *return* the user data:

```
class loginForm(forms.Form):
    # …

    def clean(self):
        user_cleaned_data=super().clean()
        password_1 = user_cleaned_data['password']
        if not set(password_1).intersection(string.ascii_uppercase):
            raise ValidationError('password','Password must have atleast one uppercase letter')
        return user_cleaned_data
```

but you do not need to use a `clean` method here. It is quite easy to work with a regex validator instead:

```
class loginForm(forms.Form):
    gender_options=[('male','Male'),('female','Female')]
    username=forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=15
    )
    email=forms.EmailField()
    password=forms.CharField(
        min_length=8,
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator('[A-Z]', 'Password must have atleast one uppercase letter')
        ]
    )
    gender=forms.ChoiceField(choices=gender_options)
```

so there is *no* need to override `clean` here. Usually `clean` is only used to verify a condition that spans *multiple* fields. Not a single field.

Comment: Thanks for your advice on the code best practises. I am still learning the basics so more concerned on the logical side of things as of now. I will keep your suggestion in mind though :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out with some shell printing. The issue is if you have a validation error thrown by the inbuilt validators, the element will not be passed on to the `super().clean()`  . So basically I was trying to find the key that didnt exist. I've added a check condition to see if the key exists and now its working fine. My updated code:

```
def clean(self):
    user_cleaned_data=super().clean()
    print(user_cleaned_data)
    email_1=user_cleaned_data['email']
    flag=False   # to find atleast 1 uppercase letter
    if 'password' in user_cleaned_data.keys():   #The added check for the key
        password_1=user_cleaned_data['password']
        if not set(password_1).intersection(string.ascii_uppercase):
            raise ValidationError('Password must have atleast one uppercase letter')
```